# Recycler View Adapter: Best practice to notify that data set has updated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to make a volley request to api's url. The problem is that data is fetched appropriately, but every time data set updates, the whole recycler view refreshes again and begins from the start; in the docs it is mentioned that use `notifyDataSetChanged()` as the last resort. How can it be avoided and what are the best practices for such tasks? Any design pattern that should be followed?

Here is the Fragment Code :-

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment implements SortDialogCallback {

    private static final String TAG = PageFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    /**
     * Unsplash API, By Default=10
     */
    private static final String per_page = "10";
    public static String order_By;
    /**
     * Unsplash API call parameter, By Default=latest
     * Change it in Pager Fragment, based on Tab tapped
     */
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager;
    EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener scrollListener;
    FloatingActionButton actionButton;
    FrameLayout no_internet_container;
    Bundle savedInstanceState;
    // Attaching Handler to the main thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    boolean shouldHandlerRunAgain = true;
    private ArrayList<DataModel> model;
    /**
     * Handler is attached to the Main Thread and it's message queue, because it is the one who created it.
     * <p>
     * Handler is responsible for checking every second that are we connected to internet, and if we are, then :-
     * 1. Then we remove empty view
     * 2. Make the network call
     * 3. Stop handler from posting the code again using shouldHandlerRunAgain variable
     * 3.1 This is a kill switch otherwise handler will post the runnable again and again to the message queue, which will be executed as soon as it reaches the looper
     * <p>
     * Handler removeCallbacks is used to remove all the pending runnables  in the Message Queue
     */
    Runnable job = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Thread run " + job.hashCode());
            swapViews();
            if (shouldHandlerRunAgain)
                handler.postDelayed(job, HANDLER_DELAY_TIME);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("ORDER_BY", order_By);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (handler != null)
        handler.post(job);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting Handler");
        layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(layoutManager) {

            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                Log.w(TAG, "On load More Called with page number " + page);
                loadDataUsingVolley(page, order_By);
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.search:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Async task", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Invalid Options", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_page_fragment, menu);
    }


    private void swapViews() {
        if (detectConnection(getContext()) == false) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            actionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            no_internet_container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Removing callbacks from handler and stopping it from posting");
            shouldHandlerRunAgain = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(job, null);
            handler = null;
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            actionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_internet_container.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                loadDataUsingVolley(1, savedInstanceState.getString("ORDER_BY"));
            } else {
                order_By = "latest";
                loadDataUsingVolley(1, order_By);
            }
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

        actionButton = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.sort_button);
        actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SortDialog sortDialog = new SortDialog();
                sortDialog.setTargetFragment(PageFragment.this, 911);
                sortDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "sortfragment");
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        no_internet_container = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.no_internet_container);

        return view;
    }

    void setUpRecyclerView() {
        if (imageAdapter == null)
            imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getContext(), (model==null)?new ArrayList<DataModel>():model);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
    }

    void loadDataUsingVolley(int page, String order_by) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Wallser", "Loading");
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        String URL = "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?page=" + page + "&client_id=" + api_key + "&per_page=" + per_page + "&order_by=" + order_by;
        Log.d(TAG, URL);
        JsonArrayRequest objectRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray array) {
                int len = array.length();
                if (model == null)
                model = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = object.getString("id");
                        JSONObject object1 = object.getJSONObject("urls");
                        String imageURL = object1.getString("regular");
                        JSONObject object2 = object.getJSONObject("links");
                        String downloadURL = object2.getString("download");
                        model.add(new DataModel(imageURL, downloadURL, id));
                        Log.d(TAG, downloadURL);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                Log.d(TAG, model.size() + "");
                setUpRecyclerView();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);
    }

    /**
     * marks a new network call to Unsplash API
     * Thus, set model array list to null, to start fresh.
     * as model is reset, ImageAdapter also needs to start fresh.
     *
     * @param order_by
     */
    @Override
    public void onDialogFinish(String order_by) {
        model = null;
        imageAdapter=null;
        order_By = order_by;
        loadDataUsingVolley(1, order_By);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think there is no way without using notifyDataSetChanged() because it is native android list behaviour. Did you try to save current scroll position or the current index and load it?

Comment: No @AbdullahTellioglu I didnt do that, though created a new method in my  CustomAdapter , a swapDataSet(Collection newDataSet) method and called notifyDataSetChaged() here in this function. But I still wonder what is making the recycler view to start again?

Comment: where are you calling the notifydatasetchanged method when your issue happens?

Comment: @ScottS initially I was calling it in setupRecyclerView() but now I have moved it to the adapter class,